# Proof that absolute value of supremum equals suprememum of absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Can someone prove that |sup(A)|=sup|A| ? Please and thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I assume we need separate cases:
Case 1. all elements of A are greater than 0, so we simple have |sup(A)|=sup(A)=sup|A|
but it gets tricker when we have negative elements

Comment: By $\sup |A|$ you mean $\displaystyle\sup_{a\in A} |a|$ right? If so, this is false. Consider $A = \{-1, 0\}$.

Comment: @ZeroXLR yes, that is standard notation.

Comment: You'll want something like $\max\{\sup(A),-\inf(A)\}$

Answer (score 3):

It is false: if $A=[-1,0]$, then $\sup A=0=\lvert\sup A\rvert$, while $\lvert A\rvert=[0,1]$ and $\sup\lvert A\rvert=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A=(-\infty,0)$. $|\sup A|=0$, but $\sup|A|=\infty$.